# Is it possible to drive a table/collection view's scrolling from gestures inside another view?

Tags: ios, iphone

Suppose there are two UIVIew subclasses in two different regions of the screen.

The first UIView subclass is a table or collectionView
The second view is a simple UIView.

Is it possible for gestures inside the second view to be "carried over" to the first view so that for example, a swipe up gesture in the second view would make the table/collection view scroll up ?

Comment: Do you want touches on both views to scroll the table view? Or just touches on the second view?

Comment: @robmayoff:  ideally, touches on both views would scroll the tableView

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In [WWDC 2012 Session 223: Enhancing User Experience with Scroll Views](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2012/223/), Apple engineers explained that you can take a scroll view's `panGestureRecognizer` and add it to a different view to make that other view control the scroll view's scrolling.

Note that `UITableView` and `UICollectionView` are subclasses of `UIScrollView`.

So if you can put your table view and your second view into a common superview, you can move the table view's `panGestureRecognizer` to the superview and it will detect touches on both subviews.

```
[commonSuperview addGestureRecognizer:tableView.panGestureRecognizer];
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way to achieve that is to encapsulate your 2 views in a another view and to add the GestureRecognizer on the motherView.
This way when the gesture triggers, with the location of the touch you can figure out if it started in one view or the other and you can track the move all the way to the second view.